# I want to make just 1 api call every 5 minutes. How can I achieve this using gatling?

Tags: scala, performance-testing, scala-collections, gatling

I want to make only 1 api call every 5 minutes for "ConsumerApi.RunConsumer". The 'Flow1' should run continuously.

I hava a scenario class:

```
object ConsumerApi {
 //Defines the Consumer API call
   val PostConsumerApi = http("Consumer API")
     .post("http://abc.abc.com/v1/execute")
     .headers(Headers.applicationJson)
     .check(status is 200)


   val RunConsumer = scenario("Run the Consumer")
     .pace(5 minutes)
     .exitBlockOnFail {
      exec(PostConsumerApi)
   }
   }
```

Then I have the simulation class:

```
class TestFlow extends Simulation {
val httpConfTest = http.baseURL(Environment.apiHost)
val Scenarios = List(
Flow1.Flow1
   .inject(constantUsersPerSec(10) during (30 minutes))  
   // Has to run for 30 minutes continuously. 
,
ConsumerApi.RunConsumer
  .inject(constantUsersPerSec(1) during (30 minutes))   
  // has to make only 1 api call every 5 minutes for duration of 30 minutes
 )
 setUp(Scenarios)
.protocols(httpConfTest).maxDuration(40 minutes)              .assertions(global.responseTime.max.lessThan(Environment.maxResponseTime.toInt))
.assertions(global.failedRequests.percent.lessThan(70))          .assertions(global.responseTime.percentile2.lessThan(Environment.maxResponseTime.toInt))
```

}

Answer (score -1):

What about the following:

```
ConsumerApi.RunConsumer
  .inject(atOnceUsers(1),
          nothingFor(5 minutes),
          atOnceUsers(1),
          nothingFor(5 minutes),
          //And so on...
    )   
 )
```

You might want to take a look at the [injection documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/current/general/simulation_setup/) for a detailed description of the available injection building blocks.